Sign of product of two integrals
Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded regular subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $\lambda_k$ with $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2\leq\lambda_3\leq...\uparrow\infty$ be the sequence of eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ with  homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition, and $e_k$ the corresponding eigenfunctions. Namely, for any $k\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $e_k$ is the solution to
$$
\begin{array}{rclll}
-\Delta e_k(\mathbf{x})&=&\lambda_k e_k(\mathbf{x}), & \text{for}\quad\mathbf{x}\in \Omega, \\ 
 e_k(\mathbf{x})&=&0, &\text{for}\quad  \mathbf{x}\in \partial\Omega.
\end{array}
$$
Furthermore, the eigenfunctions are normalized in $L^2(\Omega)$, that is $\displaystyle\int_\Omega e_i(\mathbf{x}) e_j(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} =\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol.
My question is : for $u,v\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $u,v\geq 0$, what can we say about the sign of
$$
\Big(\int_\Omega u(\mathbf{x}) e_k(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}\Big) \times \Big(\int_\Omega v(\mathbf{x}) e_k(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}\Big)?
$$
Thank you very much in advance.

You can’t say anything about the sign for $k>1$. Call $$F_k(u,v)= \bigg (\int_\Omega u e_k \,dx \bigg )  \bigg (\int_\Omega v e_k \,dx \bigg ) . $$
For $k>1$, the eigenfunctions change sign, so if $\operatorname{supp} u \subset \{e_k>0\}$ and $\operatorname{supp} v \subset \{e_k>0\}$ then $F_k(u,v)>0$; however, if $\operatorname{supp} u \subset \{e_k>0\}$ and $\operatorname{supp} v \subset \{e_k<0\}$ then $F_k(u,v)<0$.
The above argument doesn’t work for $k=1$ since the first eigenfunction doesn’t change sign, so $F_k(u,v) \geq 0$.

Thank you very much for your help.
